# How to use directive if in Angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

I have custom directive and use it in template:

```
<input check-value-type>
```

How to use this directive by condition like as:

```
<input @if(model.value) check-value-type @end />
```

Or to do somithing as:

```
@if(cond)
<input check-value-type />
@else
<input/>
@endif
```

Comment: why do you want to set a directive if it has a model? that should be managed via your link function

Comment: I iterate object in `ng-repeat` and item of iteration has different type. If it is integer I dont need to use directive, that shows additional inputs

Comment: please dont use the angular tag in angularjs related questions

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<input ng-if="typeOf model.Value !== 'number'" check-value-type />
<input ng-if="typeOf model.Value === 'number'" />
```

But the ng-if expression should be put in a model function you can access and not directly inside the ng-if statement.

```
<input ng-if="!checkValue(model.value)" check-value-type>
<input ng-if="checkValue(model.value)" />
```

inside your controller:

```
this.checkValue = function(value) {
    return typeOf value === number
}
```

This will render only one input according your case, although it looks like there are two inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Type script file you can set loggedIn= true or false and based on this boolean value we can manipulate the DOM.

```
<ul  *ngIf="loggedIn">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul  *ngIf="!loggedIn">
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Also in angular4 we can have if else

```
<div *ngIf="loggedIn; else list_two">
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #list_two>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</ng-template>
```

OR if then else

```
<div *ngIf="loggedIn;then list_one else list_two"></div>

<ng-template #list_one>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #list_two>
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.x provides ngIf, a directive to conditionally run/compile a tag.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

This allows you to conditionally render a tag on a page based on a condition that evaluates to a boolean. In your case:

`<input ng-if="model.value"/>`

Or if you have a function `checkValue(param)` in scope that returns a boolean:

`<input ng-if="checkValue(value)"/>`

Minor Addendum:

Angular also provides ngShow/ngHide, which will simply not display the element but will still generate its code. This is desirable if you plan to toggle the visibility or need its code to still execute.

Comment: I use 1.5 version Angular JS

Comment: I can also parameter to directive as `<input type-value="$$node.type_value$$" type-element="5">` but it returns undefined in directive when I try to access this:  `var type = attrs.typeElement;`

Comment: Is input a custom directive? I don't know what code the typeElement attribute is getting passed to.